# C Programming - Program Crashes

Tags: c, printf

I have a question

> "Write a C program that accepts as input a single integer k, then writes a pattern consisting of a single 1 on the first line, two 2s on the second line, three 3s on the third line, and so forth, until it writes k occurrences of k on the last line."

For example, if the input is `5`, the output should be the following:

```
1
2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
```

I have written the below code to achieve this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
int k = 5;
int i;
int j;
for(i = 1; i<=k; i++){
    for(j = 1; j<=i; j++){
        printf('%d',i);
        }
    printf('\n');
    }
return 0;
}
```

When I run this program, Eclipse crashes. Is there something I am missing in the code I wrote ?

Comment: There should be at least a warning for `printf('%d',i);`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change

```
printf('%d',i);
```

to

```
printf("%d",i);
```

and also,

```
printf('\n');
```

to

```
printf("\n");
```

Reason: As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) of `printf()`, the function prototype is

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

which says, the first argument should be a `const char *`.

Usually, `" "` is used to denote (const) `char *` as oppossed to `' '` which is used to denote a `char` constant.

Note: Enable warnings in your compiler and pay heed to them. Most of the time compiler warns you about the mistatch in agument and parameter type mismatch.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf('%d',i);
```

should be

```
printf("%d",i);
```

The first argument of `printf()` expects `const char *` and what you have is a character for it. Compiler should have thrown a warning for this before you went ahead and hit a crash. Don't ignore warnings!!

Answer (score 0):

In `printf`, you have to pass the character pointer.

change this

```
printf('%d',i);
```

into

```
printf("%d",i);
```

`printf` definition.

```
   int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look into documentation of C programming printf function require a string i.e. const char *format, and string is represented by double quotes(" "). So replace single quotes (' ') by double quotes (" ").

Answer (score 0):

The output format for `printf` in c library is

```
printf("data type representation", the data to be printed);
```

So in output stream you must use double quotes instead of single.
Following code will work fine,

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int k,i,j;
    scanf("%d",&k);
    for(i=1;i<=k;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
        printf("%d",i);

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```